# If else error : How to make it print with any number?

Tags: c++

The code should convert negative numbers to 0.

The negative numbers worked but positive numbers don't work

```cpp
int main() {

   int userNum = 0;

   if (userNum >= 0)
      cout << "Non-negative" << endl;
   else
      cout << "Negative; converting to 0" << endl;

   userNum = 0;

   cout << "Final: " << userNum << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Expected output when user use 99

```
Non-negative 
Final: 99
```

Comment: If you don't need the logging messages you could use `userNum = std::max(0, userNum);` to make sure the negative values are converted to 0.

Comment: use curly braces at all times -- especially if you are just starting to learn C or C++.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, this is week 2 for me ...

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. It's a legitimate question. SO is getting a tad downvote-happy.

Answer (score 2):

You are unconditionally setting `userNum` to 0, regardless of its previous value, before printing the `Final` message.  This is because your `else` block is missing a set of curly braces:

```cpp
int main() {

   int userNum = 0;

   cout << "Enter a number: ";
   cin >> userNum;

   if (userNum >= 0)
      cout << "Non-negative" << endl;
   else
   { // <-- add this!
      cout << "Negative; converting to 0" << endl;
      userNum = 0;
   } // <-- add this!

   cout << "Final: " << userNum << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```